# If the representation of  on  is irreducible, is the representation of × on End() also irreducible?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\rho : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ a finite-dimensional representation. Then we have a representation of the group $G \times G$ on $\mathrm{End}(V)$ via
$$(g, h) \cdot \varphi = \rho(g) \circ \varphi \circ \rho(h)^{-1}.$$
**Question.** If the representation of $G$ on $V$ is irreducible, is the representation of $G \times G$ on $\mathrm{End}(V)$ also irreducible?

Comment: Yes; this is an external tensor product and external tensor products of finite-dimensional irreducible representations are irreducible.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: More explicitly, for $v \in V$ and $f \in V^*$, we have
$$
(g,h) \cdot [vf] = \rho(g)(v) f\circ \rho(h)^{-1} = [\rho(g)(v)][\rho(h)^{-*}(f)],
$$
which allows us to identify this map with the tensor product $\rho \otimes \rho^*$. Here, $vf$ denotes the map $[vf](w) = f(w)v$.